# Using Observer/ Observable from rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to create a Observable and Observer as following

I am expecting this will trigger the onNext on observer. This is what my understanding is.

Let me know if this understanding is ok? Because its not working this way.

Psuedo code:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

    static eventname = [];
    static observable:Observable<string[]>;
    constructor() { this.init(); }

    init() {
        subscribe();
        eventhandler = function (name) {
            HeroService.eventname.push(name);
        };
    }

    subscribe(): void {
       HeroService.observable = Observable.of (HeroService.eventname);

        var observer = {
            next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
            error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
            complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
        };
         HeroService.observable.subscribe (observer);
    }     
}
```

When eventhandler is called, I add the new event to eventname. 
I expected that observer will be called. But on inspecting I found that there are no subscribers. array is lenth 0

eventHandler is called by WebSocket/SignalR Hub from server.

Answer (score 0):

you need subscribe to your observable.

```
this.observable.subscribe(observer);
```

learn more from this tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-creating-observable-from-scratch

Comment: Have added that. Forgot to write it into pseudo code. Anyway. So but that gets called during init only once. and then 'complete' message is send automatically. So that when change the eventname observer is not triggered,

Comment: Now it gets triggered only once during initialization. After that if I check there are no subscriber available with observer. How it got cleared?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting `HeroService.observable = Observable.of (HeroService.eventname);` to "watch" the event name array. That's not really how that works. Something has to emit (or next) the value.

Instead of trying to use a observer and observable maybe try using a Subject instead. Make sure to only expose only the observable part of the subject.

Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html')
})
export class HomeComponent {
    private eventNames = [];
    private eventListSubject: Subject<string[]> = new Subject<string[]>();

    constructor() {
    }

    get eventList(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.eventListSubject;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.eventList.subscribe(
            (x) => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
            (err) => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
            ()=> console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
        );
    }

    eventHandler(name: string): Function {
        return (name) => {
            this.eventNames.push(name);
            this.eventListSubject.next(this.eventNames);
        }
    }
}
```